# Typescript, ts-jest import .ts file instead of .js file with same names

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a test file and the file that test imports. Something like:

```js
// fileA.spec.ts

import fileA from "services/fileA"

// do stuff....
```

Now I have another build process that may run and will generate the equivalent JS file which leaves me with a file structure that looks like

```
src
- services
-- fileA.ts
-- fileA.js --> this is generated by a build script
-- fileA.spec.ts
```

If I run my jest test **before** running the script that creates the JS file, the tests run fine and pass. However, if I run them after then the import tries to import the JS file and causes errors.

How can I configure typescript or TS-jest to resolve imports to TS files and ignore JS files ? Below are my config files.

```json
// tsconfig.json 

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "scripts",
    "lib": [ "dom", "es7" ],
    "module": "ES2015",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "config/*": ["config/*"],
      "interfaces/*": ["interfaces/*"],
      "modules/*": ["modules/*"],
      "services/*": ["services/*"],
      "third-party/*": ["third-party/*"],
      "vue-components/*": ["vue-components/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.vue"
  ]
}
```

```js
// jest.config.js

const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest')
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig')

/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  roots: ['<rootDir>'],
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "<rootDir>"],
  modulePaths: [compilerOptions.baseUrl],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths),
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "ts", "json", "vue"],
  transform: {
    // process `*.ts` files with `ts-jest`
    "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
    // process `*.vue` files with `vue-jest`
    ".*\\.vue$": "vue-jest"
  },
  testRegex: [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./jest-setup.ts"]
};
```

Comment: Not sure if this is an option for you, but vitest has almost (actual?) full-API compatibility with jest and in my experience makes testing TS projects significantly less painful, to the point where we've pulled the trigger on migrating even some legacy stuff to it. Food for thought.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for the tip! That is definitely an option as this is part of a project to migrate away from an old SystemJS stack running karma/Jasmine tests currently. 

I did try to see if Vitest would solve my issue but it appears to do the same thing jest does. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-dncfcz?file=test%2Fbasic.test.ts

You can see in the link, I added a js file with the same name as the ts file under test in basic.test.ts and it ends up importing the js file instead of the ts file. The tests would all pass if it imports the ts file.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this was to modify the order of `moduleFileExtensions`.

In your case, instead of:

`moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "ts", "json", "vue"],`

try to use:

`moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js", "json", "vue"],`

See [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulefileextensions-arraystring).

Comment: Wow! right there in the documentation. That looks like it would have definitely addressed the problem. I won't be able to test it out as I ultimately just threw it away and went the Vitest route and had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's hard to answer the question without checking your main project config files. However, some generic tips may be useful for you.
You can just configure TypeScript and Jest to resolve imports to TS files and ignore JS files by adjusting the configuration in your tsconfig.json and Jest configuration.

### **1. Update tsconfig.json:**

Make sure your tsconfig.json has the following compiler options:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    // other options...

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

The "baseUrl" and "paths" settings help TypeScript resolve imports based on the src directory.

### **2. Update Jest configuration (jest.config.js or in package.json):**

Add the transform configuration to explicitly tell Jest to use ts-jest and ignore JavaScript files:

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  // other Jest configurations...
};
```

### **3. Ensure ts-jest is installed:**

Make sure you have ts-jest installed as a development dependency:

```
npm install --save-dev ts-jest
```

### **4. Run Jest:**

After making these changes, run your Jest tests. It should now resolve imports to TypeScript files and ignore JavaScript files.

These configurations help TypeScript and Jest work together, ensuring that TypeScript files are prioritized in the import resolution process. This should solve the issue you're facing with Jest trying to import the generated JS file.

Comment: I appreciate the tips. I updated the question above to include my current project configs. I believe they already include everything you've suggested here and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @Jmh2013 Can you please post your sample project to play with it and see what is going wrong? Just a sample to see what is going on

Comment: Here is a link to a very simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-m7fses?file=tsconfig.json
There is an `index.js` and an `index.ts`. The test file imports `index` without an extension. I'd like Typescript to import ts files by default when importing. If you run the tests, they'll fail because index.js is empty. Delete or rename it so it imports the ts file and the tests will pass.